# Как можно привязать тип данных sql bit к datagridview datasource?

Tags: c#, sql, исключения

Работаю над курсовой с базой SQL, возникла проблема, что логическое значение, указанное в столбце не хочет правильно работать.

ОШИБКА: System.ArgumentException: "Привязка к свойству или столбцу Реализован для DataSource невозможна.
Имя параметра: dataMember"

Так как можно привязать тип данных sql bit к datagridview или так сделать нельзя?

Код, если нужен:

```
private void OrdersForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string datasource = @"DESKTOP-PFSPO89\SQLEXPRESS";
string database = "Matryoshka_DataBase";
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + datasource + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=SSPI");

da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Заказы", con);
ds = new DataSet();
con.Open();
da.Fill(ds, "MyTABLE");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTABLE"];
con.Close();
}
```

Comment: В какой именно строке ошибка?

Comment: У грида столбцы автогенерируемые или заданы вручную?